# Realtime retrieve online users, authenticated with Identity Blazor (Server / WebAssembly)

Tags: server, blazor, identity, webassembly

I am creating a chat in Blazor (Server / WebAssembly), with SignalR I calmly receive the notification of receipt of messages.
How can I check who are the online users?

Answer (score 1):

With signalr you can override the hubs `OnConnectedAsync` and `OnDisconnectedAsync` :

```
public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    await notificationsService.ConnectAsync(this.ToCallerContext());
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

```
public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    await notificationsService.DisconnectAsync(this.ToCallerContext());
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```